# C# enum.ToString() boxing: resolve or supress?

Tags: c#, performance, enums, refactoring, boxing

So recently we've installed the 'Clr Heap Allocation Analyzer' extension for Visual Studio to check our code for heap allocation problems caused by boxing, among others. We've come across the warning 'HAA0102', which gives the following description:

> Non-overridden virtual method call on a value type adds a boxing or
>   constrained instruction

It refers to the condition checks in following line of code:

```
if(instanceType == Enums.Tags.DialoguePanel.ToString())
{
     // Some code handling
}
else if(instanceType == Enums.Tags.InfoPanel.ToString())
{
    // Some other code handling
}
```

For context, the Enums.Tags.DialoguePanel refers to the following enum declaration:

```
public enum Tags
        {
            InfoPanel,
            DialoguePanel,
            WarningPanel
        }
```

Now I understand that `enum` is a value type and therefore `Enums.Tags.DialoguePanel` is a value type. I also understand that to `.ToString()` is basically boxing that to a reference type (string).

My question is whether or not it is necessary to refactor these kinds of lines to avoid boxing (and if so... how?) or if it's better to suppress this warning for these specific cases? Please keep in mind that that we do need to keep the enum types. They're used as a controlled way of providing the user options (in a dropdown list). Refactoring those to be of another type will take a LOT of work (which is fine if the performance will be increased significantly).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question should be: "why do you even need the `ToString` at all? Why not comparing against the actual enum-value?

Comment: Good point. We also have cases in which we compare string values of objects to these enum.ToString(). For example, we get a 'object.name' from the WebAPI of our clients and we need to check it against our enum (string) values.

Comment: If you really need the strings – which seems like a questionable design – use `nameof(Enums.Tag.InfoPanel)` instead of calling ToString.

Comment: It's not a desirable design and a code smell, I do agree with that. Unfortunately, we have to take our data from the web server of a client. We don't have control over how they sent their data (and in what form/type).

Comment: I second the use of `nameof`, this will compile the strings as constants into the compiled code instead of producing new strings every time `.ToString()` is called. Most likely this should get rid of the warning as well.

Answer (score 4):

Enum has certain advantages over String, namely that you're adding a constraint that only valid values can be among the defined enums.  Understandably, your web server receives strings, not enum values, but the proper approach should be to force the string into an enum value, and then compare enum values.

The forcing of the string value of course can go wrong, so this should be considered a "validation step".  However once the enum value is valid, you won't encounter problems of this nature, which in addition to being a bit of a performance drop is also error-prone in my humble opinion (what happens if you expect value to match one of the enum values and *none do*?).

```
// "Validation"
instanceType = (Enums.Tags) Enum.Parse(typeof(Enums.Tags), value)

// Usage
if(instanceType == Enums.Tags.DialoguePanel)
{
     // Some code handling
}
else if(instanceType == Enums.Tags.InfoPanel)
{
    // Some other code handling
}
```

Comment: Okay, great arguments, thank you. And yes, we receive strings from a web server. Although we can try to parse the string into an enum value, the performance drop would not be desirable, obviously. So if I understand you correctly, it's better to keep it the way we have now and suppressing the warning?

Comment: You forgot the cast to the Enum type where you parse.

Comment: @FerdieQO No, my argument was about eliminating the need to check against a string in the first place.  If instanceType were an enum value, there wouldn't be this warning.

Comment: Right, got it now. Casting the value to the enum value with the Enum.Parse and then checking it against the other enum values. That should bypass the boxing (and thus the warning) and keep it from ending up allocated on the heap, right? Btw, I apologize for not completely understanding the arguments correctly. English is not my first language.

Answer (score 3):

> Now I understand that enum is a value type and therefore `Enums.Tags.DialoguePanel` is a value type. I also understand that to `.ToString()` is basically boxing that to a reference type (string).

That's not quite true. The boxing is because [`Enum.ToString`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/1365cfeffd45409d.html) calls the [`Enum.GetValue`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/ad6b58b10ae0549a.html) method, which returns the underlying value as an `object` - hence the boxing operation. The `string` is a reference type so it is not boxed. And just because of the string conversion no boxing would be necessary.

> And yes, we receive strings from a web server. Although we can try to parse the string into an enum value, the performance drop would not be desirable, obviously.

I actually created once a generic [`Enum<TEnum>`](http://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_CoreLibraries_Enum_1.htm) class for enum operations without boxing. And though the no-boxing `Enum<TEnum>.ToString` is about 20 times faster (at least in [this .NET Fiddle test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PCcVuD)), I think the performance loss caused by the boxing compared to the web server response times are negligible so you can just suppress the warning. But feel free to [give it a try](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries) if you wish.